# Tax not getting calculated in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Here is what my Woocommerce setting look like: 
[image]

According to this I should get a default tax rate of 9.5% applied. But my checkout page has been showing 0 tax all the time - irrespective of the item I select.

Can anyone help? What am I missing here?

In case it helps, here is the tax settings: 
[image]

Comment: Is that before you put in your shipping address?

Comment: Nope. I have put the shipping address. Country, state, city and zip code all are filled in. Still the tax is not getting calculated.

Comment: You need to set "Including tax" on "Display Prices During Cart and Checkout".

Comment: @Aibrean: That doesn't help. The only difference with that option is how it is shown on the website - as a separate row of 'Tax' or Total amount ($x Tax). But it doesn't change anything on the tax calculation.

Comment: With a correct configuration and it still not working, something else is amiss and I don't think it can be solved on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. This is a known issue in the recent version of WooCommerce. Tax table is missing. You can use the workaround mentioned [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-not-adding-vat-amount-to-product?replies=12#post-7254931).

Answer (score 0):

Check your theme, whether it has two different options like billing address and shipping address.
This means there are two different options for billing and shipping. Check it and change your setting of "calculate tax on basis of".

Comment: Looking at the OP's self answer from 6 years ago, there was a solution given then, and this wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the latest version of woocommerce. I am using square to process credit cards. In the image attached there is a small blue colored word that says "standard." This is a link to select. It follows the words "tax option." This is where you setup a tax rate in your website back end. Fill in the blanks by first clicking "Insert Row." Then enter your geographical location description. You must look up the tax rate for your location. Do this regardless of whether the customer's address will be used.
I did this and the tax started calculating perfectly.